# MS Test unit tests run in dotnet test but fail in VS 2022 test explorer when Mozilla VPN is active

Tags: visual-studio-2022, mstest, mozilla-vpn

When Mozilla VPN is active, the VS test explorer fails to find the test host and times out after 90 seconds, when the VPN is not active, the tests run fine. The VPN does not affect test runs via dotnet test.

I already have Visual Studio 2022 excluded in the app exclusion list of the VPN. When I try to add `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe to the list, it fails silently with no diagnostic emitted to the log.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this that doesn't involve disabling the VPN?

Comment: Maybe reboot? I wonder if Microsoft is blocking something. I wonder if vstest.console.exe is sending telemetry stats back to Microsoft, and Microsoft is blocking those incoming requests because you are on the Mozilla VPN.

Comment: I wonder if disabling telemetry and usage stats in Visual Studio would help.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, great suggestion!  Unfortunately, I didn't see your comment until I came here to post the fix Mozilla support sent me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important bits of the reply I got from Mozilla support:

> It's important to note that this is definitively an odd situation since we haven't received additional reports about this issue. Therefore, could you please try a full reset process inside the VPN app since this will let our VPN have a fresh start? To reset the Mozilla VPN app please follow the steps below:
>
> 1. Open the Mozilla VPN app
> 2. Click/tap on Settings (gear icon)
> 3. Click/tap "Get Help"
> 4. Afterward, click/tap "Get help" at the top of the screen 6 times until "Developer Options" appear below
>    5.Click/tap "Developer Options"
> 5. Scroll down and click/tap "Reset and Quit" 6 times. The app will reset.
> 6. Relaunch the VPN app and log back in with your Firefox account credentials.

Reads like a charm and worked like one as well. Problem solved.